# Is there any accepted single-word that means "partial function"?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, terminology, computer-science

When I'm explaining things involving partial functions, I usually end up stumbling over my words, like so: "Suppose $f : A \rightarrow B$ is a function, uhh, sorry I mean a partial function, and suppose $S$ denotes its support. Then there's a corresponding restriction function... um, well, really its a *partial* function, $\overline{S} : A \rightarrow A$. And $S$ is characterized as the smallest set such that $f \circ \overline{S}=f.$"

I find that initially, I intentionally correct for this, but after awhile, "relapse" occurs, maybe I'll call $\frac{1}{x}$ a function from the real line back to itself, then add something about "well, really its a *partial* function" etc., and pretty soon the explanation starts to get bogged down in these sorts of tiresome qualifications. I'll bet other people experience this, too.

Anyway, I was just wondering if there's any accepted single-word that means "partial function," since this would kind of solve the problem.

Comment: Just call it a punction and accept it.

Comment: This frequently occurs when discussing computability.  I don't think there's a single word that works, but I can suggest the following workaround against forgetting the adjectives: declare that "functions" are renamed to "total functions" and that any occurrence of "function" *must* be qualified by "partial" or "total"—and that if you ever forget to use one or the other, the audience should interrupt you if there is the slightest ambiguity.

Comment: Also, I recommend the notation $X\dashrightarrow Y$ (with a dotted / dashed arrow) to represent partial functions, rather than $X\to Y$ or even $X\rightharpoonup Y$, it's more visually distinctive.

Comment: I disagree that $X ⇢ Y$ is visually more distinctive than $X \rightharpoonup Y$.

Comment: Some use an arrow with a vertical stroke to denote a partial function and distinguish it visually from an (ordinary, total) function. I myself find it very convenient, and use it regularly when dealing with induced densities. I don't know if there is a built-in tag in the current distributions of LaTeX for something like that, but just in case you may use (a variant of) the following (after replacing each section sign "§" with a dollar):

\newcommand\pto{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hfil§\mapstochar§\hfil\hfil\cr§\to§\cr}}}

Comment: If you find yourself referring to partial functions overwhelmingly more frequently than total functions, then just clarify that by "function" you mean "partial function" and that if you want to talk about a "total function" then you'll say "total function."

Comment: By analogy with "poset" for "partially ordered set", it should be "pfunction".